# Filtering by the result of an aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
        date    id      value
0   2002-01-07  PA12165 119.63
1   2002-03-13  PA12165 119.48
2   2002-05-13  PA12165 114.50
3   2002-06-12  PA12165 120.27
4   2002-06-12  PA12165 120.27
...
```

I want to get another dataframe by filtering by the result of an aggregate function. This is my attempt:

```
my_aggs = {'id': 'count',
           'value': [min, max, 'mean']
          }
df.groupby(['id', 'date']).agg(my_aggs).query('count > 1')
```

raises: `UndefinedVariableError: name 'count' is not defined`

As you can see I can't find the way to reference my aggregate function in the query

Comment: What is your expected output

Answer (score 3):

You have a `MultiIndex`. The `count` column does not exist but `(id, count)` is:

```
# Output before query

#        MultiIndex --v
                      id   value                
                   count     min     max    mean
id      date                                    
PA12165 2002-01-07     1  119.63  119.63  119.63
        2002-03-13     1  119.48  119.48  119.48
        2002-05-13     1  114.50  114.50  114.50
        2002-06-12     2  120.27  120.27  120.27
```

To avoid pain with `MultiIndex` and `query`, you can use:

```
my_aggs = {'count': ('id', 'count'),
           'min': ('value', 'min'),
           'max': ('value', 'max'),
           'mean': ('value', 'mean')}

out = df.groupby(['id', 'date'], as_index=False).agg(**my_aggs).query('count > 1')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        id        date  count     min     max    mean
3  PA12165  2002-06-12      2  120.27  120.27  120.27
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a MultiIndex, so you need to slice both levels. Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
my_aggs = {'id': 'count',
           'value': [min, max, 'mean']
          }

(df.groupby(['id', 'date']).agg(my_aggs)
   .loc[lambda d: d[('id', 'count')] > 1]
 )
```

Output:

```
                      id   value                
                   count     min     max    mean
id      date                                    
PA12165 2002-06-12     2  120.27  120.27  120.27
```

Comment: I wanted to write an answer with `loc` but hesitated :)

Comment: @Corralien no one answers for 20 min and of.course we post at the same time! :D

Comment: Great minds meet and respond at the same time :-P lol

Answer (score 1):

```
df_agg = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).agg(my_aggs)
df2 = df_agg[df_agg[('id', 'count')] > 1]
```